# How to see if NSArray, created with valueForKey is empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, nsarray

I got an array:

```
NSArray *itemsArray = [self.tournamentDetails.groups valueForKey:@"Items"];
```

Where self.tournamentDetails.groups is an NSArray, build with a JSON string from a webRequest.

Items is sometimes empty and sometimes it contains objects. So i need an if statement to check if its empty or not. I've tried some different things like:

```
if ([itemsArray count]!=0)
if (!itemsArray || !itemsArray.count)
```

Problem is that if my Items object from valueForKey is empty then the itemsArray still contains an object looking like this

```
<__NSArrayI 0x178abef0>(
<__NSArrayI 0x16618c30>(

)

)
```

When theres items inside my Items object it looks like this:

```
<__NSArrayI 0x18262b70>(
<__NSCFArray 0x181e3a40>(
{
    BirthDate = 19601006T000000;
    ClubName = "Silkeborg Ry Golfklub";
    ClubShortName = "";
    CompletedResultSum =     {
        Actual =         {
            Text = 36;
            Value = 36;
        };
        ToPar =         {
            Text = "";
            Value = 0;
        };
    };
}
)
)
```

Meaning that [itemsArray count] is always equal to 1 or more, and then it jumps into the if statement when it should not.

Anyone know how i can create an if statement where if itemsArray contains "Items:[]" it will be skipped and if itemsArray contains "Items:[lots of objects]" it will run?

EDIT: Solution is to check up on the first index like this  if([[itemsArray objectAtIndex:0] count] != 0) then run code.

Comment: Can you please `NSLog` the `self.tournamentDetails.groups` and paste it here (or at least the part where 'Items' appear)?

Comment: sure ill update my post

Comment: self.tournamentDetails.groups what type is this ?

Comment: its an NSArray. Updated post.

Comment: If the format is constant you can also check the inner array count no? Like `[[itemsArray objectAtIndex:0] count]`

Comment: So you have array (self.tournamentDetails.groups) with arrays in it?Why do you use valueForKey to take an item from the array?Maybe this is not the best data type.

Comment: wootage, can you suggest any other way to do this? valueForKey is the only way i know how to get the Items object.

Comment: So the problem is that your `itemsArray` is an array of arrays. If the count of your outermost array is always == 1, then you probably want something like `NSArray *itemsArray = [[self.tournamentDetails.groups valueForKey:@"Items"] firstObject];`

Comment: After the web request you can build NSDictionary or MyItemsCustomClass to store the objects.As I see from the code above you have an array containing string,dictionary,int.

Comment: [[itemsArray objectAtIndex:0] count] is working it returns 0 if Items object is empty and more then 0 if its not.

Comment: wootage, self.tournamentDetails is actually an object i build from my JSON string, i can't post the JSON string cause its like 3k lines long:) so the Items array i posted was just a small sample of the hole array. each Item object contains 10 other objects

Comment: Yep , i saw it , it was totally my bad

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions, I've updated my post with a solution that worked + is simple.

Comment: @user2408952 If your itemsArray doesn't have 'objectAtIndex:0' your code will crash, you should consider using 'firstObject' instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(itemsArray && itemsArray.count>0) //be sure that it has value){
   for(NSArray *item in itemsArray){
       if(item.count > 0){
           // you have an NSDictionary. Will process it 
       }else{
           //item.count == 0 : this is an empty NSArray.
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, i found a more simple solution that worked. If([[itemsArray objectAtIndex:0] count] != 0)

Comment: @user2408952: Just my opinion, If([[itemsArray objectAtIndex:0] count] != 0) : just use for 1 item only. In case this array has more than 1 item, I think it will fail. My solution is applied for all cases.

Comment: `itemsArray && itemsArray.count > 0` is superfluous, just do `if (itemsArray.count) { //code }`

Answer (score 0):

more simpler

```
  for (id obj in itemsArray)
  {
      if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
      {
          if(obj.count > 0)
          {
             //your if condition here 
          }
      }
  }
```